# Xcode pluginDidLoad not getting called when adding objective-c file in swift plugin

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, plugins

I'm working on a plugin for Xcode. It is supposed to be written in Swift.
When I start with a fresh plugin project (I'm using this Xcode [Plugin template](https://github.com/kattrali/Xcode-Plugin-Template) which is also available via Alcatraz) the project compiles and runs fine.

The `pluginDidLoad` method is getting called right after Xcode starts. As soon as I add any Objective-C file (and a bridging header of course) the `pluginDidLoad` method is not getting called anymore.

The Objective-C file might be as simple as an empty class that is a subclass of NSObject.
Removing the target-memberbership (for the plugin-target) from the newly created Objective-C (.m) file the aforementioned mentioned method is getting called again.

Has anyone developed a Xcode plugin in Swift that also uses Objective-C files before and got this working?

Answer (score 2):

### Update

It seems that my original solution only works with Swift only projects because Xcode always takes the objective c class if you have one.

So here is another trick: Extend the NSObject class by the function `class func pluginDidLoad(bundle: NSBundle) {}` and initialize your plugin there. Then it doesn't matter on which class it is called. You might have to check that also all Swift classes subclass NSObject. I pushed it to my repository that you can have a look

### Original Post

I think I could reproduce the problem now. To simplify the problem, let's say that we have only two swift classes PluginMain and PluginHelper.

As you said, sometimes the plugin isn't getting called for some mysterious reason. I was struggling with the problem again and I was wondering how Xcode knows which class is the main class. So I came up with the idea to put the following initializer in both classes PluginMain and PluginHelper

```
class func pluginDidLoad(bundle: NSBundle) {
    let appName = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? NSString
    if appName == "Xcode" {
        //sharedPlugin = SwiftySafe(bundle: bundle)
        //initialize your shared plugin
    }
}
```

By putting a breakpoint or log message in `pluginDidLoad` in both classes, I notices that Xcode isn't ignoring the plugin, it is just loading the wrong class (e.g. PluginHelper instead of PluginMain).

### The Solution

It turns out that Xcode uses the class that is compiled first as the main class and calls `pluginDidLoad` only on that. So you can change that by reordering the "Compiled Sources" under your target settings->Build Phases. Move your main class so that it is on top. In the following image you find an example from my project. `SwiftySafe` is my main class.

[image]

### My example

You will find my project here https://github.com/creinders/SwiftySafe if you want to compare the settings.

Comment: I just checked your recommendation. Unfortunately it doesn't work. In order to make sure everything is setup correctly I forked your repo. 'pluginDidLoad' is getting called. As soon as I added just one empty objective-c class it's not getting called anymore. Here's your modified project: https://github.com/benrudhart/SwiftySafe

Comment: If you put `+ (void)pluginDidLoad:(NSBundle*)plugin
{
    NSLog(@"Test");
    
}` also in `SSEmptyObjCClass` this is getting called. Maybe my solutions only works for swift only projects... I'm trying to find out how to select the main class

Comment: It seems that Xcode always takes the objective c class if you have one. So here is another trick: Extend the NSObject class by the function `class func pluginDidLoad(bundle: NSBundle) {}`. Then it doesn't matter on which class it is called. You might have to check that also all Swift classes subclass NSObject. I pushed it to my repository that you can have a look

Answer (score 1):

The `pluginDidLoad` method is called on the principal class. When the principal class is a Swift class, you have to include the module name in the `NSPrincipalClass` Info.plist key.

So if your target name is `MyPlugin` and your principal class is `MyClass`, set `NSPrincipalClass` to `MyPlugin.MyClass`.

Also make sure that `MyClass` inherits from NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to tell Xcode to reload bundle. Run this and restart Xcode

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTPlugInManagerNonApplePlugIns-Xcode-7.3
```